# Alternatives to calculating the rank of the information matrix in determining if the model is identifiable

Tags: fisher-information, identifiability

I have a known non-linear model $h \in \mathbf{R}^n$:
$$
y = h(\theta) + \epsilon,
$$
where $\theta\in \mathbf{R}^m$ is a parameter vector, and $\epsilon$ is a normal random variable with zero mean and known covariance. Thus, the distribution of $y$ is $ \mathcal{N}(h(\theta), \Sigma$). To determine if the model $h$ is identifiable, one can use,

Rothenberg, Thomas J. “Identification in Parametric Models.” Econometrica, vol. 39, no. 3, 1971, pp. 577–591. JSTOR, JSTOR, www.jstor.org/stable/1913267.

and Theorem 1 states that if the information matrix is non-singular in $\theta_0$, then the model is locally identifiable at $\theta_0$. The information matrix in this case can be calculated as
$$
I(\theta) = \left(\frac{\partial h}{\partial \theta} \right)^T \Sigma^{-1}\left(\frac{\partial h}{\partial \theta} \right),
$$
and to know if $I$ is singular one can attack $I$ directly, or look at the rank of the Jacobian.

Now, if the function $h$ is complicated, the Jacobian may be even more complicated, and $I$ is hard to analyse. **Are there any alternatives to analyse identifiability of a model other than looking at the singularity of $I$?**